# Кадр не находиться в модуле

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, hex

Не хотел писать сюда, но ладно, я пытаюсь загрузить в память шестнадцатеричный код, и выполнить его. С++, windows.
Сам код:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>

#pragma warning(disable: 4996)

int main() {
    int size = 0;
    FILE* fp;

    fp = fopen("source.b", "rb");

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    unsigned char *code = new unsigned char[size];

    fread(code, size, 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    code[size] = '\0';

    std::cout <<"Size: " << size << "\nCode: " << code << '\n';

    FARPROC mcd = (FARPROC)VirtualAlloc(NULL, size, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    if (!mcd) return -1;
    CopyMemory(mcd, code, size);

    mcd();

    VirtualFree(mcd, size, MEM_RELEASE);
    return 0;
}
```

Я получаю ошибку "Кадр не находиться в модуле, Текущий кадр стека не найден в загруженном модуле."
Как её можно исправить?
В файле source.b один NOP, 0x90.

Comment: Прежде подумайте над тем, что же в итоге вы пытаетесь запихнуть в выделенный участок виртуальной памяти; во-вторых, для шелл-кода достаточно `VirtualProtect`.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю что это было, но после перезапуска ide программа начала выполнять машинный код с файла на ура....

[image: результат]

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).